# Swift 4 ImageScrollView resizing visible cells in UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, resize

I am using the ImageScrollView cocoa pod v1.5 inside a UITableViewCell (Swift 4). 
I am downloading images from Firestore using SDWebImage (but also tried Kingfisher with no change in my issue). My images are 700x700 and are being displayed in a ImageScrollView that, depending upon device, is about 400x100. I have set the SDWebImage *imageContentMode* to .*widthFill*. I rotate the image to get it in the form I want for the tableview. I use it in it's regular orientation in other places.
The first time my cells are shown the images are shown correctly. If I go back to the previous page, then show the same results in the table again, the visible cells will have their images no longer fitting correctly with regards to width, they are now too wide. If I scroll down hiding those cells all new cells are properly displayed, when I scroll back up the incorrect cells are now displaying correctly. Happens in simulator and actual phone.

Here are the important parts of my UITableViewCell class :

```
class MyTableCell: UITableViewCell {
var ski : Ski!
var skiImageView: UIImageView = UIImageView()
@IBOutlet weak var skiImageScrollView: ImageScrollView!


 func configureCell(ski: Ski) {
    self.ski = ski
    let imageUrl = ski.imageUrl!
    let url = URL(string: imageUrl)
     skiImageView.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: placeholderImage, options: [.retryFailed, .continueInBackground]
        , completed: {
            (image, error, cacheType, url) in
            if (error != nil) {
                print("ConfigureCell Error : \(error!)")
                return;
            }
            let rotatedImage = self.imageRotatedByDegrees(oldImage: image!, deg: 90.0)
            self.skiImageScrollView.display(image: rotatedImage)                var image = self.skiImageView.image!
            self.skiImageScrollView.imageContentMode = .widthFill

    })
```

}

```
func imageRotatedByDegrees(oldImage: UIImage, deg degrees: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
    //Calculate the size of the rotated view's containing box for our drawing space
    let rotatedViewBox: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: oldImage.size.width, height: oldImage.size.height))
    let t: CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: degrees * CGFloat.pi / 180)
    rotatedViewBox.transform = t
    let rotatedSize: CGSize = rotatedViewBox.frame.size
    //Create the bitmap context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rotatedSize)
    let bitmap: CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    //Move the origin to the middle of the image so we will rotate and scale around the center.
    bitmap.translateBy(x: rotatedSize.width / 2, y: rotatedSize.height / 2)
    //Rotate the image context
    bitmap.rotate(by: (degrees * CGFloat.pi / 180))
    //Now, draw the rotated/scaled image into the context
    bitmap.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
    bitmap.draw(oldImage.cgImage!, in: CGRect(x: -oldImage.size.width / 2, y: -oldImage.size.height / 2, width: oldImage.size.width, height: oldImage.size.height))
    let newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage
}
```

Another strange thing is if I slap the back of my phone or drop it on my desk, the images will jump down so only parts of the top of my image are visible in the ImageScrollView, but callbacks from ImageScrollView for zooming are not activated, so no idea what is happening there either.

Comment: I added code to print out the height and width of the imageScrollView.bounds. The width is growing when they are displayed incorrectly. Visually the imageScrollView doesn't change since I have a border on it. Its resizing it's internal bounds for some reason. ImageScrollView.bounds.width is what I am printing. This is a correct value :Width = 355.0  and this is when its displaying incorrectly : Width = 393.666666666667. I have user interaction disabled for the imageScrollView. As noted in comments below, removing the rotation code has no effect on the issue. Why are the bounds changing?

Answer (score 0):

You might try the following:

`imageScrollView.imageContentMode = .aspectFit`

before

`self.skiImageScrollView.display(image: rotatedImage)`

Comment: The image is oversized for the space provided in both height and width, I am showing the top half of the image, shrunken down to fit the width. If I do aspect fit it makes the image a little square in the middle of the available space. It's strange in that only the visible cells do this, and only after they have been displayed once. I messed with the caching to no effect. Then when you scroll them off the screen and back they are shown correctly. Very strange.

Comment: I removed the image rotation code to eliminate that as a possible source of the issue. Without rotating the image I experience the same behavior.

Comment: I guess it didn't make a difference if you set the imageContentMode before calling .display on the view?